# I trying to create a DB schema based on a JSON file

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database, schema

I am trying to create a DB based on a JSON file but I am messing up the keys and references. Can you guys have a look and tell me whats wrong with the create statement?
The json files are basically reviews or comments from people and there are 7 response objects and one cursor object in this json file.
JSON file:

```
{
   "cursor": {
      "prev": null,
      "hasNext": false,
      "next": "1542275432008325:1:0",
      "hasPrev": false,
      "total": null,
      "id": "1542275432008325:1:0",
      "more": false
   },
   "code": 0,
   "response": [
      {
         "editableUntil": "2018-11-22T11:20:37",
         "dislikes": 0,
         "numReports": 0,
         "likes": 1,
         "message": "<p>A sinking pound, resignations by the bucketful railroading through a so-called agreement nobody wants. For the good of the country Mrs. May 'go and go now'.</p>",
         "id": "4196155749",
         "createdAt": "2018-11-15T11:20:37",
         "author": {
            "username": "mnaid-233509073ed3432027d48b1a83f5fbd2",
            "about": "",
            "name": "baggiebuoy",
            "disable3rdPartyTrackers": true,
            "isPowerContributor": false,
            "joinedAt": "2017-05-03T10:40:52",
            "profileUrl": "https://disqus.com/by/mnaid-233509073ed3432027d48b1a83f5fbd2/",
            "url": "",
            "location": "",
            "isPrivate": false,
            "signedUrl": "",
            "isPrimary": true,
            "isAnonymous": false,
            "id": "250728493",
            "avatar": {
               "small": {
                  "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-233509073ed3432027d48b1a83f5fbd2.jpg",
                  "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar32.png"
               },
               "isCustom": false,
               "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-233509073ed3432027d48b1a83f5fbd2.jpg",
               "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png",
               "large": {
                  "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-233509073ed3432027d48b1a83f5fbd2.jpg",
                  "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png"
               }
            }
         },
         "media": [],
         "isSpam": false,
         "isDeletedByAuthor": false,
         "isDeleted": false,
         "parent": null,
         "isApproved": true,
         "isFlagged": false,
         "raw_message": "A sinking pound, resignations by the bucketful railroading through a so-called agreement nobody wants. For the good of the country Mrs. May 'go and go now'.",
         "isHighlighted": false,
         "canVote": false,
         "thread": "7046384220",
         "forum": "expressandstar",
         "points": 1,
         "moderationLabels": [],
         "isEdited": true,
         "sb": false
      },
      {
         "editableUntil": "2018-11-22T10:37:59",
         "dislikes": 0,
         "numReports": 0,
         "likes": 0,
         "message": "<p>This could be heaven, or this could be hell.</p>",
         "id": "4196048572",
         "createdAt": "2018-11-15T10:37:59",
         "author": {
            "username": "mnaid-29e1c59be16c852670e3be302e8c303b",
            "about": "",
            "name": "Mordecai",
            "disable3rdPartyTrackers": false,
            "isPowerContributor": false,
            "joinedAt": "2017-05-03T13:01:02",
            "profileUrl": "https://disqus.com/by/mnaid-29e1c59be16c852670e3be302e8c303b/",
            "url": "",
            "location": "",
            "isPrivate": false,
            "signedUrl": "",
            "isPrimary": true,
            "isAnonymous": false,
            "id": "250739494",
            "avatar": {
               "small": {
                  "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-29e1c59be16c852670e3be302e8c303b.jpg",
                  "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar32.png"
               },
               "isCustom": false,
               "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-29e1c59be16c852670e3be302e8c303b.jpg",
               "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png",
               "large": {
                  "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-29e1c59be16c852670e3be302e8c303b.jpg",
                  "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png"
               }
            }
         },
         "media": [],
         "isSpam": false,
         "isDeletedByAuthor": false,
         "isDeleted": false,
         "parent": 4196013534,
         "isApproved": true,
         "isFlagged": false,
         "raw_message": "This could be heaven, or this could be hell.",
         "isHighlighted": false,
         "canVote": false,
         "thread": "7046384220",
         "forum": "expressandstar",
         "points": 0,
         "moderationLabels": [],
         "isEdited": false,
         "sb": false
      },
      {
         "editableUntil": "2018-11-22T10:36:50",
         "dislikes": 0,
         "numReports": 0,
         "likes": 0,
         "message": "<p>The crappest of crap deals.<br>Will never get through Parliament.</p><p>You are the weakest link May, goodbye.</p>",
         "id": "4196044068",
         "createdAt": "2018-11-15T10:36:50",
         "author": {
            "username": "mnaid-29e1c59be16c852670e3be302e8c303b",
            "about": "",
            "name": "Mordecai",
            "disable3rdPartyTrackers": false,
            "isPowerContributor": false,
            "joinedAt": "2017-05-03T13:01:02",
            "profileUrl": "https://disqus.com/by/mnaid-29e1c59be16c852670e3be302e8c303b/",
            "url": "",
            "location": "",
            "isPrivate": false,
            "signedUrl": "",
            "isPrimary": true,
            "isAnonymous": false,
            "id": "250739494",
            "avatar": {
               "small": {
                  "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-29e1c59be16c852670e3be302e8c303b.jpg",
                  "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar32.png"
               },
               "isCustom": false,
               "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-29e1c59be16c852670e3be302e8c303b.jpg",
               "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png",
               "large": {
                  "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-29e1c59be16c852670e3be302e8c303b.jpg",
                  "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png"
               }
            }
         },
         "media": [],
         "isSpam": false,
         "isDeletedByAuthor": false,
         "isDeleted": false,
         "parent": null,
         "isApproved": true,
         "isFlagged": false,
         "raw_message": "The crappest of crap deals.\nWill never get through Parliament.\n\nYou are the weakest link May, goodbye.",
         "isHighlighted": false,
         "canVote": false,
         "thread": "7046384220",
         "forum": "expressandstar",
         "points": 0,
         "moderationLabels": [],
         "isEdited": false,
         "sb": false
      },
      {
         "editableUntil": "2018-11-22T10:28:13",
         "dislikes": 0,
         "numReports": 0,
         "likes": 0,
         "message": "<p>We are all just prisoners here of our own device. </p>",
         "id": "4196013534",
         "createdAt": "2018-11-15T10:28:13",
         "author": {
            "username": "mnaid-42ba513c42a0fd6558aa44b1de658140",
            "about": "",
            "name": "chaffwolf",
            "disable3rdPartyTrackers": true,
            "isPowerContributor": false,
            "joinedAt": "2017-12-20T16:45:10",
            "profileUrl": "https://disqus.com/by/mnaid-42ba513c42a0fd6558aa44b1de658140/",
            "url": "",
            "location": "",
            "isPrivate": false,
            "signedUrl": "",
            "isPrimary": true,
            "isAnonymous": false,
            "id": "274657487",
            "avatar": {
               "small": {
                  "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-42ba513c42a0fd6558aa44b1de658140.jpg",
                  "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar32.png"
               },
               "isCustom": false,
               "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-42ba513c42a0fd6558aa44b1de658140.jpg",
               "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png",
               "large": {
                  "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-42ba513c42a0fd6558aa44b1de658140.jpg",
                  "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png"
               }
            }
         },
         "media": [],
         "isSpam": false,
         "isDeletedByAuthor": false,
         "isDeleted": false,
         "parent": 4195981074,
         "isApproved": true,
         "isFlagged": false,
         "raw_message": "We are all just prisoners here of our own device. ",
         "isHighlighted": false,
         "canVote": false,
         "thread": "7046384220",
         "forum": "expressandstar",
         "points": 0,
         "moderationLabels": [],
         "isEdited": false,
         "sb": false
      },
      {
         "editableUntil": "2018-11-22T10:27:03",
         "dislikes": 0,
         "numReports": 0,
         "likes": 0,
         "message": "<p>Should be no deal end off.<br>Nobody could possibly be the winner so it's simple leave and that's it .<br>Their will always be wannabes who think they can do better in it for only their own powers not for the general country or the people of it .,</p>",
         "id": "4196012501",
         "createdAt": "2018-11-15T10:27:03",
         "author": {
            "username": "mnaid-90ecce8d5dad4396f681182cb470872c",
            "about": "",
            "name": "wanderer in eire",
            "disable3rdPartyTrackers": true,
            "isPowerContributor": false,
            "joinedAt": "2017-05-12T20:20:43",
            "profileUrl": "https://disqus.com/by/mnaid-90ecce8d5dad4396f681182cb470872c/",
            "url": "",
            "location": "",
            "isPrivate": false,
            "signedUrl": "",
            "isPrimary": true,
            "isAnonymous": false,
            "id": "251694793",
            "avatar": {
               "small": {
                  "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-90ecce8d5dad4396f681182cb470872c.jpg",
                  "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar32.png"
               },
               "isCustom": false,
               "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-90ecce8d5dad4396f681182cb470872c.jpg",
               "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png",
               "large": {
                  "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-90ecce8d5dad4396f681182cb470872c.jpg",
                  "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png"
               }
            }
         },
         "media": [],
         "isSpam": false,
         "isDeletedByAuthor": false,
         "isDeleted": false,
         "parent": null,
         "isApproved": true,
         "isFlagged": false,
         "raw_message": "Should be no deal end off.\nNobody could possibly be the winner so it's simple leave and that's it .\nTheir will always be wannabes who think they can do better in it for only their own powers not for the general country or the people of it .,",
         "isHighlighted": false,
         "canVote": false,
         "thread": "7046384220",
         "forum": "expressandstar",
         "points": 0,
         "moderationLabels": [],
         "isEdited": false,
         "sb": false
      },
      {
         "editableUntil": "2018-11-22T10:26:42",
         "dislikes": 0,
         "numReports": 0,
         "likes": 0,
         "message": "<p>Damned if she does, damned if she doesn't. All for a cause she does not believe in.<br>She will go down in history whatever happens. <br>The question is: who better to lead the country at such an important juncture??<br>Answers on a postcard!</p>",
         "id": "4196012237",
         "createdAt": "2018-11-15T10:26:42",
         "author": {
            "username": "mnaid-42ba513c42a0fd6558aa44b1de658140",
            "about": "",
            "name": "chaffwolf",
            "disable3rdPartyTrackers": true,
            "isPowerContributor": false,
            "joinedAt": "2017-12-20T16:45:10",
            "profileUrl": "https://disqus.com/by/mnaid-42ba513c42a0fd6558aa44b1de658140/",
            "url": "",
            "location": "",
            "isPrivate": false,
            "signedUrl": "",
            "isPrimary": true,
            "isAnonymous": false,
            "id": "274657487",
            "avatar": {
               "small": {
                  "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-42ba513c42a0fd6558aa44b1de658140.jpg",
                  "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar32.png"
               },
               "isCustom": false,
               "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-42ba513c42a0fd6558aa44b1de658140.jpg",
               "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png",
               "large": {
                  "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-42ba513c42a0fd6558aa44b1de658140.jpg",
                  "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png"
               }
            }
         },
         "media": [],
         "isSpam": false,
         "isDeletedByAuthor": false,
         "isDeleted": false,
         "parent": null,
         "isApproved": true,
         "isFlagged": false,
         "raw_message": "Damned if she does, damned if she doesn't. All for a cause she does not believe in.\nShe will go down in history whatever happens. \nThe question is: who better to lead the country at such an important juncture??\nAnswers on a postcard!",
         "isHighlighted": false,
         "canVote": false,
         "thread": "7046384220",
         "forum": "expressandstar",
         "points": 0,
         "moderationLabels": [],
         "isEdited": false,
         "sb": false
      },
      {
         "editableUntil": "2018-11-22T09:50:32",
         "dislikes": 0,
         "numReports": 0,
         "likes": 0,
         "message": "<p>Theresa May is using The Eagles Hotel California lyrics as the inspiration for her Brexit plan.</p><p>You can check out any time you like, but you can never leave.</p>",
         "id": "4195981074",
         "createdAt": "2018-11-15T09:50:32",
         "author": {
            "username": "mnaid-e82a88d937e60267fd2c866b01131ada",
            "about": "",
            "name": "Olly the cat",
            "disable3rdPartyTrackers": false,
            "isPowerContributor": false,
            "joinedAt": "2017-05-03T10:27:23",
            "profileUrl": "https://disqus.com/by/mnaid-e82a88d937e60267fd2c866b01131ada/",
            "url": "",
            "location": "",
            "isPrivate": false,
            "signedUrl": "",
            "isPrimary": true,
            "isAnonymous": false,
            "id": "250727584",
            "avatar": {
               "small": {
                  "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-e82a88d937e60267fd2c866b01131ada.jpg",
                  "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar32.png"
               },
               "isCustom": false,
               "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-e82a88d937e60267fd2c866b01131ada.jpg",
               "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png",
               "large": {
                  "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-e82a88d937e60267fd2c866b01131ada.jpg",
                  "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png"
               }
            }
         },
         "media": [],
         "isSpam": false,
         "isDeletedByAuthor": false,
         "isDeleted": false,
         "parent": null,
         "isApproved": true,
         "isFlagged": false,
         "raw_message": "Theresa May is using The Eagles Hotel California lyrics as the inspiration for her Brexit plan.\n\nYou can check out any time you like, but you can never leave.",
         "isHighlighted": false,
         "canVote": false,
         "thread": "7046384220",
         "forum": "expressandstar",
         "points": 0,
         "moderationLabels": [],
         "isEdited": false,
         "sb": false
      }
   ]
}
```

SQL Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE cursor(
code DOUBLE NOT NULL,
hasNext VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
next VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
hasPrev VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
more VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (hasNext),
FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES dbjson(code)
)


CREATE TABLE small(
isCustom VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
permalink VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
cache VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (permalink),
FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES avatar(isCustom)
)


CREATE TABLE moderationLabels(
editableUntil VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES response(editableUntil)
)


CREATE TABLE large(
isCustom VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
permalink VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
cache VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (permalink),
FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES avatar(isCustom)
)


CREATE TABLE response(
code DOUBLE NOT NULL,
editableUntil VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
dislikes DOUBLE NOT NULL,
numReports DOUBLE NOT NULL,
likes DOUBLE NOT NULL,
message VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
createdAt VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
isSpam VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
isDeletedByAuthor VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
isDeleted VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
isApproved VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
isFlagged VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
raw_message VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
isHighlighted VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
canVote VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
thread VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
forum VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
points DOUBLE NOT NULL,
isEdited VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
sb VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (editableUntil),
FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES dbjson(code)
)


CREATE TABLE author(
editableUntil VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
about VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
disable3rdPartyTrackers VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
isPowerContributor VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
joinedAt VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
profileUrl VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
url VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
location VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
isPrivate VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
signedUrl VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
isPrimary VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
isAnonymous VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
id DOUBLE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (username),
FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES response(editableUntil)
)


CREATE TABLE avatar(
username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
isCustom VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
permalink VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
cache VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (isCustom),
FOREIGN KEY (editableUntil) REFERENCES author(username)
)


CREATE TABLE media(
editableUntil VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES response(editableUntil)
)


CREATE TABLE dbjson(
code DOUBLE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (code))
```

Comment: Please add the error message you are getting, or the expected and actual data.

Answer (score 1):

When you define foreign keys, you must define the parent table before you can define a child table that references it. Your tables are defined in an order such that several tables references their parent before the parent is created.

Next problem: `cursor` is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in MySQL. You must delimit it with back-ticks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `cursor`(
...
```

Next problem: Several tables declare a foreign key on a column that doesn't exist in the table. For example, `author` has:

```
FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES response(editableUntil)
```

But the `author` table has no column called `code`. The column must exist in the table before you can declare a foreign key on it. The same problem occurs in tables `avatar`, `small`, `moderationLabels`, `large`, and `media`.